# Bacon.js combine properties with .and() only if prop === true

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

I've picked up Bacon.js recently and doing some UI with it in which I only enable a 'Sign up' button if the requirements are met, one of them is check that the username is valid.

```
// Returns true or string with invalid reason
var isUsernameValid = username
    .map(function(value) {
        if(value.length < 4) {
            return 'Must be 4 characters at least';
        }

        if(!config.patterns['username'].test(value)) {
            return 'Can only have letters, numbers, periods, or underscores';
        }

        return true;
    });
```

It either returns true or why the username is invalid.

Later I combine all the results with this:

```
password.and(username).and(isUsernameValid)
    .not().assign($(view['signup-submit']), 'toggleClass', 'disabled');
```

Username and password are only true when there's input, but since `isUsernameValid` always returns a *truthy* value the buttons ends up being incorrectly enabled.

Is there a better way to return errors or combine properties by passing a function?

I thought of declaring another stream/property to return if the `value === true`  but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because your truthy value includes both valid and invalid cases. That function never returns falsy values. How about seperating invalid and valid into truthy and falsy values?

```
var isUsernameInvalid = username
  .map(function(value) {
    if(value.length < 4) {
      return 'Must be 4 characters at least';
    }

    if(!config.patterns['username'].test(value)) {
      return 'Can only have letters, numbers, periods, or underscores';
    }

    return false;
});
```

Then, without much change to the original code

```
password.and(username).and(isUsernameInvalid.not())
  .not().assign($(view['signup-submit']), 'toggleClass', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
var isUsernameLongEnough = username.map(function(value) {
  return value.length >= 4
})
var usernameHasCorrectCharacters = username.map(function(value) {
  return config.patterns['username'].test(value)
})

var isUsernameValid = isUsernameLongEnough.and(usernameHasCorrectCharacters)

password.and(username).and(isUsernameValid)
    .not().assign($(view['signup-submit']), 'toggleClass', 'disabled')

isUsernameLongEnough.not().assign($(view['error-too-short']), 'toggle')
usernameHasCorrectCharacters.not().assign($(view['error-invalid-characters']), 'toggle')
```

It is better to keep each function small and separate the concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I ended up changing my function to return either a Bacon.Next or Bacon.Error and transform the property based on that.